# OpenGL and GLM matrix doesn't scale properly, always scales down

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glm-math

When I use glm::scale to update the model matrix in my vertex shader, no matter what I do, it will always scale it down. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? The image will sometimes flip up and down too.

The key == 'w' and key == 's' do the exact same thing despite the code being different, the goal is to make the model grow bigger by pressing W and smaller by pressing S. But right now it just gets smaller with both presses.

The relevant code used to scale according to key press is:

```
if (key == 'w') {
        model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5));
        int loc = glGetUniformLocation(prog, "model");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
    }
    if (key == 's') {
        model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5));
        int loc = glGetUniformLocation(prog, "model");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
    }
```

The whole code is:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <SOIL.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include "OBJ.h"

const char* vs = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;\n"
"layout (location = 1) in vec2 texpos;\n"
"out vec2 texCoords;\n"
"uniform mat4 model;\n"
"uniform mat4 view;\n"
"uniform mat4 projection;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(pos, 1);\n"
"texCoords = texpos;\n"
"}\0";

const char* fs = "#version 330 core\n"
"in vec2 texCoords;\n"
"out vec4 fragColor;\n"
"uniform sampler2D tex;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"fragColor = texture(tex, texCoords);"
"}\0";

float verts[] = {
    0, 1, 0, 0.5, 1,
    -1, -1, 0, 0, 0,
    1, -1, 0, 1, 0
};

unsigned short indices[] = {
    0, 1, 2
};

unsigned int vao, vbo, ebo, prog, vert, frag, texid;

glm::mat4 model, view, projection;


void changeViewPort(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

void render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void initGL() {
    //Context stuff
    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);
    glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    //Shader stuff
    int success;
    prog = glCreateProgram();
    vert = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vert, 1, &vs, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vert);
    glGetShaderiv(vert, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    std::cout << "Vertex shader " << (success ? "compiled" : "not compiled") << std::endl;

    frag = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(frag, 1, &fs, NULL);
    glCompileShader(frag);
    glGetShaderiv(frag, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    std::cout << "Fragment shader " << (success ? "compiled" : "not compiled") << std::endl;

    glAttachShader(prog, vert);
    glAttachShader(prog, frag);

    glLinkProgram(prog);
    glUseProgram(prog);

    glGetShaderiv(prog, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    std::cout << "Program " << (success ? "linked" : "not linked") << std::endl;

    glDeleteShader(vert);
    glDeleteShader(frag);
    //Vertex stuff
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), &verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), (void*)(3 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), &indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    //Texture stuff
    int width, height;
    unsigned char* texData = SOIL_load_image("brick.png", &width, &height, NULL, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);

    glGenTextures(1, &texid);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    if (texData) {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texData);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    } else {
        std::cout << "Texture not loaded." << std::endl;
    }
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    SOIL_free_image_data(texData);

    //Matrix stuff
    //Model matrix
    model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5));
    int modelMatrix = glGetUniformLocation(prog, "model");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
    //View matrix
    view = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0, 0, -3));
    int viewMatrix = glGetUniformLocation(prog, "view");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewMatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
    //Projection matrix, something is messing up here
    projection = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), 800.0f / 600.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    int projectionMatrix = glGetUniformLocation(prog, "projection");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionMatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

}

void input(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    if (key == 'a') {
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(-0.5, 0, 0));
        int loc = glGetUniformLocation(prog, "model");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
    }
    if (key == 'd') {
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.5, 0, 0));
        int loc = glGetUniformLocation(prog, "model");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
    }
    if (key == 'w') {
        model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5));
        int loc = glGetUniformLocation(prog, "model");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
    }
    if (key == 's') {
        model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5));
        int loc = glGetUniformLocation(prog, "model");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
    }
    if (key == 'q') {

        model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(45.0f), glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
        int loc = glGetUniformLocation(prog, "model");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
    }
    if (key == 'e') {

        model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(-45.0f), glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
        int loc = glGetUniformLocation(prog, "model");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // Initialize GLUT
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("OBJ Viewer");
    glutReshapeFunc(changeViewPort);
    glutDisplayFunc(render);
    glutKeyboardFunc(input);
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "GLEW error");
        return 1;
    }
    initGL();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x*0.5` and `x*-0.5` are both scale down, isn't it?

Comment: No because if x is 1, then 1 * 0.5 = 0.5 and 1 * -0.5 = -0.5 so the former should scale it up by 0.5 and the latter should scale it down by 0.5

Comment: no it not work that way, let me ask you what is `(x*0.5)*0.5` and what is `(x*-0.5)*-0.5`

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying. But how do I fix this in my code? What do I change in my code to make it scale up by half a coordinate and scale down properly by half a coordinate?

Comment: If you want to scale up then scale with a value > 1. Btw. scaling with negative values can result in mirroring.

Comment: If I scale with 1 or -1 it just disappears either way. I am seriously lost on whats going on.

Comment: it should not disappear. if it works for `0.5`, no reason it'd not work for `1`, but did you try `1.2`?

Comment: anyway if I got you correct, you want to move each vertex further from origin by constant distance. in which case afaict cannot be done in model matrix, but you may add a new parameter (e.g. `uniform float displacement` in shader and modify your shader like `vec4 pos = projection * view * model * vec4(pos, 1); gl_Position = pos*(length(pos)+displacement/length(pos));`

Comment: oh and for the above formula you should also check for `pos==0`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by half a coordinate, but it's clear that you want to change size by an absolute value, while the scale matrix is relative to the model. In fact, you should also consider what happens when the model is not around the origin - the space between the model and the origin is also scaled!

to get an absolute size change, I'd suggest to calculate the model's bounding box, and the desired size. The ratio of the two will go into the scale function. For example, if the model's bounding box is (20, 10, 5), and you want it to be (19.5, 9.5, 4.5), then you need `scale(20/19.5, 10/19.5, 5/4.5)`.

Calculating a model's bounding box should be done after each rotation change. In the general case, you can do it on the CPU, going over the CPU-transformed vertices and taking the min and max of each coordinate. There may be faster methods depending on your special circumstances.

Comment: [RE:your first paragraph.] Operate on model matrix only rely on local origin, which should be always reliable.

Comment: also, you should probably include *how* to get bounding box.

Comment: Edited per your suggestion. Your 1st comment is unfortunately not relevant. I've met models whose vertices are all offset compared to the local origin, so the origin is not inside the model.

Comment: arguably your origin model matrix should adjust that, then scale would still works.

Comment: Of course after enough matrix multiplications of the right kind everything will be fine :) you just have to know it's there.

Answer (score 0):

When you scale your model, you pass the model matrix and scale vector to glm::scale function. When you do `model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5));`, this means **multiplying** your model size by `0.5`, **instead of  adding**. Same with `-0.5`. That's why your model always scales down.

As far as I understand, you want your model to scale up and down by 50 % when pressing 'w' and 's' respectively. So, simply use `model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(1.5, 1.5, 1.5));` to scale up and `model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5));` to scale down.